# How can I read RSA keys in Java?

Tags: java, cryptography, rsa, x509, pkcs#8

I am trying to read the RSA public and private keys files in Java.

My RSA public and private key is generated using PuttyGen. (SSH-2 RSA, 1024 bits)

The code I am using for reading file is:

```
//public key
pubkeyBytes = getBytesFromFile(new File(pubKeyfileName));
KeySpec pubSpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(pubkeyBytes);
RSAPublicKey pubKey =(RSAPublicKey) rsakeyFactory.generatePublic(pubSpec);

//private key
privkeyBytes = getBytesFromFile(new File(privKeyfileName));
PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privSpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privkeyBytes);
PrivateKey privKey = rsakeyFactory.generatePrivate(privSpec);
```

It throws:

```
java.security.InvalidKeyException: invalid key format
    at sun.security.x509.X509Key.decode(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 6):

Putty uses its own key format. You need to export the Putty key to the OpenSSH format - see [How to convert SSH keypairs generated using PuttyGen(Windows) into key-pairs used by ssh-agent and KeyChain(Linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224066/how-to-convert-ssh-keypairs-generated-using-puttygenwindows-into-key-pairs-use).

Then, you need to convert the OpenSSH key to pkcs8 format - see [How to Load RSA Private Key From File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243018/how-to-load-rsa-private-key-from-file). The Cygwin version of openssh will work just fine for this; there's no need to find a Unix system to run `openssh`.

Comment: OpenSSL can also be compiled for the Windows command shell, although I personally like the Bash shell in Cygwin better too.