# How to read PuTTYgen RSA Keys in Java

Tags: java, security, rsa

I'm using PuTTYgen to generate RSA Keys and export them to the OpenSSH format. They then look like this

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,14EB795C6D5C665D
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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

which is just an arbitrary SSH2-RSA key with the passphrase "test123" (w/o quotes).

When stored as a file, how can I read this information in Java to use it as

```
RSAPublicKey
```

and

```
RSAPrivateKey
```

Please try to be as detailed as possible, I know the very basics of cryptography but I'm far from being an expert...

Comment: It might be duplicated with [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12663084/how-can-i-read-rsa-keys-in-java).

Comment: alijandro is right, one of the options is to convert putty keystore to PKCS#12 keystore and read them with java.security.KeyStore. Another option will be parse format by hand. You should tell, which option is suitable for you and what do you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to decode the OpenSSH key and the result will be a KeyPair

```
try {
 String PEMPrivateKey = "...";
 String password = "";
 java.security.KeyPair key = PEMDecoder.decodeKeyPairOpenSSH(PEMPrivateKey, password);
 java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey pub = (java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey)key.getPublic();
} catch (IOException e) {
 // key not in new OpenSSH key format
}
```

Below is the PEM decoder from the [trilead SSH project](https://github.com/jenkinsci/trilead-ssh2).

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.CharArrayReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import com.trilead.ssh2.crypto.cipher.AES;
import com.trilead.ssh2.crypto.cipher.BlockCipher;
import com.trilead.ssh2.crypto.cipher.CBCMode;
import com.trilead.ssh2.crypto.cipher.DES;
import com.trilead.ssh2.crypto.cipher.DESede;
import com.trilead.ssh2.crypto.digest.MD5;
import com.trilead.ssh2.signature.DSAPrivateKey;
import com.trilead.ssh2.signature.DidECKeyPair;
import com.trilead.ssh2.signature.ECDSAKeyAlgorithm;
import com.trilead.ssh2.signature.KeyAlgorithm;
import com.trilead.ssh2.signature.KeyAlgorithmManager;
import com.trilead.ssh2.signature.RSAPrivateKey;

import org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1ObjectIdentifier;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x9.ECNamedCurveTable;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x9.X9ECParameters;
import org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.ec.KeyFactorySpi;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.spec.ECPrivateKeySpec;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.spec.ECPublicKeySpec;
import org.bouncycastle.math.ec.ECPoint;

/**
 * PEM Support.
 * 
 * @author Christian Plattner, plattner@trilead.com
 * @version $Id: PEMDecoder.java,v 1.2 2008/04/01 12:38:09 cplattne Exp $
 */
public class PEMDecoder
{
    private static final int PEM_RSA_PRIVATE_KEY = 1;
    private static final int PEM_DSA_PRIVATE_KEY = 2;
    private static final int PEM_EC_PRIVATE_KEY = 3;

    private static final int hexToInt(char c)
    {
        if ((c >= 'a') && (c <= 'f'))
        {
            return (c - 'a') + 10;
        }

        if ((c >= 'A') && (c <= 'F'))
        {
            return (c - 'A') + 10;
        }

        if ((c >= '0') && (c <= '9'))
        {
            return (c - '0');
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Need hex char");
    }

    private static byte[] hexToByteArray(String hex)
    {
        if (hex == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("null argument");

        if ((hex.length() % 2) != 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Uneven string length in hex encoding.");

        byte decoded[] = new byte[hex.length() / 2];

        for (int i = 0; i < decoded.length; i++)
        {
            int hi = hexToInt(hex.charAt(i * 2));
            int lo = hexToInt(hex.charAt((i * 2) + 1));

            decoded[i] = (byte) (hi * 16 + lo);
        }

        return decoded;
    }

    private static byte[] generateKeyFromPasswordSaltWithMD5(byte[] password, byte[] salt, int keyLen)
            throws IOException
    {
        if (salt.length < 8)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Salt needs to be at least 8 bytes for key generation.");

        MD5 md5 = new MD5();

        byte[] key = new byte[keyLen];
        byte[] tmp = new byte[md5.getDigestLength()];

        while (true)
        {
            md5.update(password, 0, password.length);
            md5.update(salt, 0, 8); // ARGH we only use the first 8 bytes of the
            // salt in this step.
            // This took me two hours until I got AES-xxx running.

            int copy = (keyLen < tmp.length) ? keyLen : tmp.length;

            md5.digest(tmp, 0);

            System.arraycopy(tmp, 0, key, key.length - keyLen, copy);

            keyLen -= copy;

            if (keyLen == 0)
                return key;

            md5.update(tmp, 0, tmp.length);
        }
    }

    private static byte[] removePadding(byte[] buff, int blockSize) throws IOException
    {
        /* Removes RFC 1423/PKCS #7 padding */

        int rfc_1423_padding = buff[buff.length - 1] & 0xff;

        if ((rfc_1423_padding < 1) || (rfc_1423_padding > blockSize))
            throw new IOException("Decrypted PEM has wrong padding, did you specify the correct password?");

        for (int i = 2; i <= rfc_1423_padding; i++)
        {
            if (buff[buff.length - i] != rfc_1423_padding)
                throw new IOException("Decrypted PEM has wrong padding, did you specify the correct password?");
        }

        byte[] tmp = new byte[buff.length - rfc_1423_padding];
        System.arraycopy(buff, 0, tmp, 0, buff.length - rfc_1423_padding);
        return tmp;
    }

    private static final PEMStructure parsePEM(char[] pem) throws IOException
    {       
        PEMStructure ps = new PEMStructure();

        String line = null;

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new CharArrayReader(pem));

        String endLine = null;

        while (true)
        {
            line = br.readLine();

            if (line == null)
                throw new IOException("Invalid PEM structure, '-----BEGIN...' missing");

            line = line.trim();

            if (line.startsWith("-----BEGIN DSA PRIVATE KEY-----"))
            {
                endLine = "-----END DSA PRIVATE KEY-----";
                ps.pemType = PEM_DSA_PRIVATE_KEY;
                break;
            }

            if (line.startsWith("-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"))
            {
                endLine = "-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";
                ps.pemType = PEM_RSA_PRIVATE_KEY;
                break;
            }
            
            if (line.startsWith("-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----"))
            {
                endLine = "-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----";
                ps.pemType = PEM_EC_PRIVATE_KEY;
                break;
            }           
        }

        while (true)
        {
            line = br.readLine();

            if (line == null)
                throw new IOException("Invalid PEM structure, " + endLine + " missing");

            line = line.trim();

            int sem_idx = line.indexOf(':');

            if (sem_idx == -1)
                break;

            String name = line.substring(0, sem_idx + 1);
            String value = line.substring(sem_idx + 1);

            String values[] = value.split(",");

            for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
                values[i] = values[i].trim();

            // Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
            // DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,579B6BE3E5C60483

            if ("Proc-Type:".equals(name))
            {
                ps.procType = values;
                continue;
            }

            if ("DEK-Info:".equals(name))
            {
                ps.dekInfo = values;
                continue;
            }
            /* Ignore line */
        }

        StringBuffer keyData = new StringBuffer();

        while (true)
        {
            if (line == null)
                throw new IOException("Invalid PEM structure , " + new String(pem) + endLine + " missing");

            line = line.trim();

            if (line.startsWith(endLine))
                break;

            keyData.append(line);

            line = br.readLine();
        }

        char[] pem_chars = new char[keyData.length()];
        keyData.getChars(0, pem_chars.length, pem_chars, 0);

        ps.data = Base64.decode(pem_chars);

        if (ps.data.length == 0)
            throw new IOException("Invalid PEM structure, no data available");

        return ps;
    }

    private static PEMStructure parsePEM(char[] pem, CertificateDecoder certificateDecoder) throws IOException
    {
        PEMStructure ps = new PEMStructure();

        String line;

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new CharArrayReader(pem));

        String endLine;

        while (true)
        {
            line = br.readLine();

            if (line == null)
                throw new IOException("Invalid PEM structure, '-----BEGIN...' missing");

            line = line.trim();

            if (line.startsWith(certificateDecoder.getStartLine()))
            {
                endLine = certificateDecoder.getEndLine();
                break;
            }

        }

        while (true)
        {
            line = br.readLine();

            if (line == null)
                throw new IOException("Invalid PEM structure, " + endLine + " missing");

            line = line.trim();

            int sem_idx = line.indexOf(':');

            if (sem_idx == -1)
                break;

            String name = line.substring(0, sem_idx + 1);
            String value = line.substring(sem_idx + 1);

            String values[] = value.split(",");

            for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
                values[i] = values[i].trim();

            // Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
            // DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,579B6BE3E5C60483

            if ("Proc-Type:".equals(name))
            {
                ps.procType = values;
                continue;
            }

            if ("DEK-Info:".equals(name))
            {
                ps.dekInfo = values;
                continue;
            }
            /* Ignore line */
        }

        StringBuilder keyData = new StringBuilder();

        while (true)
        {
            if (line == null)
                throw new IOException("Invalid PEM structure, " + endLine + " missing");

            line = line.trim();

            if (line.startsWith(endLine))
                break;

            keyData.append(line);

            line = br.readLine();
        }

        char[] pem_chars = new char[keyData.length()];
        keyData.getChars(0, pem_chars.length, pem_chars, 0);

        ps.data = Base64.decode(pem_chars);

        if (ps.data.length == 0)
            throw new IOException("Invalid PEM structure, no data available");

        return ps;
    }

    
    private static final void decryptPEM(PEMStructure ps, byte[] pw) throws IOException
    {
        if (ps.dekInfo == null)
            throw new IOException("Broken PEM, no mode and salt given, but encryption enabled");

        if (ps.dekInfo.length != 2)
            throw new IOException("Broken PEM, DEK-Info is incomplete!");

        String algo = ps.dekInfo[0];
        byte[] salt = hexToByteArray(ps.dekInfo[1]);

        BlockCipher bc = null;

        if (algo.equals("DES-EDE3-CBC"))
        {
            DESede des3 = new DESede();
            des3.init(false, generateKeyFromPasswordSaltWithMD5(pw, salt, 24));
            bc = new CBCMode(des3, salt, false);
        }
        else if (algo.equals("DES-CBC"))
        {
            DES des = new DES();
            des.init(false, generateKeyFromPasswordSaltWithMD5(pw, salt, 8));
            bc = new CBCMode(des, salt, false);
        }
        else if (algo.equals("AES-128-CBC"))
        {
            AES aes = new AES();
            aes.init(false, generateKeyFromPasswordSaltWithMD5(pw, salt, 16));
            bc = new CBCMode(aes, salt, false);
        }
        else if (algo.equals("AES-192-CBC"))
        {
            AES aes = new AES();
            aes.init(false, generateKeyFromPasswordSaltWithMD5(pw, salt, 24));
            bc = new CBCMode(aes, salt, false);
        }
        else if (algo.equals("AES-256-CBC"))
        {
            AES aes = new AES();
            aes.init(false, generateKeyFromPasswordSaltWithMD5(pw, salt, 32));
            bc = new CBCMode(aes, salt, false);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new IOException("Cannot decrypt PEM structure, unknown cipher " + algo);
        }

        if ((ps.data.length % bc.getBlockSize()) != 0)
            throw new IOException("Invalid PEM structure, size of encrypted block is not a multiple of "
                    + bc.getBlockSize());

        /* Now decrypt the content */

        byte[] dz = new byte[ps.data.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < ps.data.length / bc.getBlockSize(); i++)
        {
            bc.transformBlock(ps.data, i * bc.getBlockSize(), dz, i * bc.getBlockSize());
        }

        /* Now check and remove RFC 1423/PKCS #7 padding */

        dz = removePadding(dz, bc.getBlockSize());

        ps.data = dz;
        ps.dekInfo = null;
        ps.procType = null;
    }

    public static final boolean isPEMEncrypted(PEMStructure ps) throws IOException
    {
        if (ps.procType == null)
            return false;

        if (ps.procType.length != 2)
            throw new IOException("Unknown Proc-Type field.");

        if ("4".equals(ps.procType[0]) == false)
            throw new IOException("Unknown Proc-Type field (" + ps.procType[0] + ")");

        if ("ENCRYPTED".equals(ps.procType[1]))
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    public static Object decode(char[] pem, String password) throws IOException
    {
        PEMStructure ps = parsePEM(pem);

        if (isPEMEncrypted(ps))
        {
            if (password == null)
                throw new IOException("PEM is encrypted, but no password was specified");

            decryptPEM(ps, password.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
        }

        if (ps.pemType == PEM_DSA_PRIVATE_KEY)
        {
            SimpleDERReader dr = new SimpleDERReader(ps.data);

            byte[] seq = dr.readSequenceAsByteArray();

            if (dr.available() != 0)
                throw new IOException("Padding in DSA PRIVATE KEY DER stream.");

            dr.resetInput(seq);

            BigInteger version = dr.readInt();

            if (version.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) != 0)
                throw new IOException("Wrong version (" + version + ") in DSA PRIVATE KEY DER stream.");

            BigInteger p = dr.readInt();
            BigInteger q = dr.readInt();
            BigInteger g = dr.readInt();
            BigInteger y = dr.readInt();
            BigInteger x = dr.readInt();

            if (dr.available() != 0)
                throw new IOException("Padding in DSA PRIVATE KEY DER stream.");

            return new DSAPrivateKey(p, q, g, y, x);
        }

        if (ps.pemType == PEM_RSA_PRIVATE_KEY)
        {
            SimpleDERReader dr = new SimpleDERReader(ps.data);

            byte[] seq = dr.readSequenceAsByteArray();

            if (dr.available() != 0)
                throw new IOException("Padding in RSA PRIVATE KEY DER stream.");

            dr.resetInput(seq);

            BigInteger version = dr.readInt();

            if ((version.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) != 0) && (version.compareTo(BigInteger.ONE) != 0))
                throw new IOException("Wrong version (" + version + ") in RSA PRIVATE KEY DER stream.");

            BigInteger n = dr.readInt();
            BigInteger e = dr.readInt();
            BigInteger d = dr.readInt();

            return new RSAPrivateKey(d, e, n);
        }

        if (ps.pemType == PEM_EC_PRIVATE_KEY)
        {
            SimpleDERReader DERderReader = new SimpleDERReader(ps.data);

            byte[] sequence = DERderReader.readSequenceAsByteArray();

            if (DERderReader.available() != 0) {
                throw new IOException("Unexpected padding in EC private key");
            }

            SimpleDERReader sequenceReader = new SimpleDERReader(sequence);
            
            BigInteger version = sequenceReader.readInt();
            if ((version.compareTo(BigInteger.ONE) != 0)) {
                throw new IOException("Unexpected version number in EC private key: " + version);
            }

            byte[] privateBytes = sequenceReader.readOctetString();

            String curveOid = null;
            byte[] publicBytes = null;
            while (sequenceReader.available() > 0) {
                int type = sequenceReader.readConstructedType();
                SimpleDERReader fieldReader = sequenceReader.readConstructed();
                switch (type) {
                    case 0:
                        curveOid = fieldReader.readOid();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        publicBytes = fieldReader.readOctetString();
                        break;
                }
            }

            ASN1ObjectIdentifier asn1 = new ASN1ObjectIdentifier(curveOid);
            X9ECParameters x9 = ECNamedCurveTable.getByOID(asn1);
            
            BigInteger s = new BigInteger(1, privateBytes);
            byte[] publicBytesSlice = new byte[publicBytes.length - 1];
            System.arraycopy(publicBytes, 1, publicBytesSlice, 0, publicBytesSlice.length);
            ECPoint w = ECDSAKeyAlgorithm.decodePoint(publicBytesSlice, x9.getCurve());

            didisoft.sftp.bouncycastle.math.ec.ECCurve curve = x9.getCurve();
            ECPrivateKeySpec privSpec = new ECPrivateKeySpec(s, new didisoft.sftp.bouncycastle.jce.spec.ECParameterSpec(curve, x9.getG(), x9.getN()));
            ECPublicKeySpec pubSpec = new ECPublicKeySpec(w, new didisoft.sftp.bouncycastle.jce.spec.ECParameterSpec(curve, x9.getG(), x9.getN()));

            try {
                                
                // BC hack because jce-impl KeyFactorySpi.generatePublic doesn't support java.security.spec.ECPublicKeySpec !
                // KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");
                KeyFactorySpi.ECDSA factory = new KeyFactorySpi.ECDSA();
                PublicKey ecPublicKey = factory.engineGeneratePublic(pubSpec);
                PrivateKey ecPrivateKey = factory.engineGeneratePrivate(privSpec);
                
                return new DidECKeyPair(ECNamedCurveTable.getName(asn1), ecPublicKey, ecPrivateKey);
            } catch (InvalidKeySpecException ex) {
                throw new IOException("Could not generate EC key pair: " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        }       
        
        throw new IOException("PEM problem: it is of unknown type");
    }


    public static Object decodeKeyPairOpenSSH(char[] pem, String password) throws IOException
    {
        KeyPair key = decodeKeyPair(pem, password);
        if (key.getPrivate() instanceof java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey) {
            java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateCrtKey rsa = (java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateCrtKey)key.getPrivate();
            return new RSAPrivateKey(rsa.getPrivateExponent(), rsa.getPublicExponent(), rsa.getModulus());
        } else if (key.getPrivate() instanceof java.security.interfaces.DSAPrivateKey) {
            java.security.interfaces.DSAPublicKey dsaPub = (java.security.interfaces.DSAPublicKey)key.getPublic();
            java.security.interfaces.DSAPrivateKey dsaPriv = (java.security.interfaces.DSAPrivateKey)key.getPrivate();
            return new DSAPrivateKey(dsaPub.getParams().getP(), 
                    dsaPub.getParams().getQ(), 
                    dsaPub.getParams().getG(), 
                    dsaPub.getY(), 
                    dsaPriv.getX());
        } else {
            return null;
        }       
    }
    
    /**
     * Decodes keys in the new OpenSSH format
     * @param pem
     * @param password
     * @return
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static KeyPair decodeKeyPair(char[] pem, String password) throws IOException
    {

        for (KeyAlgorithm<PublicKey, PrivateKey> algorithm : KeyAlgorithmManager.getSupportedAlgorithms()) {
            for (CertificateDecoder decoder : algorithm.getCertificateDecoders()) {
                try {
                    PEMStructure ps = parsePEM(pem, decoder);

                    if (isPEMEncrypted(ps)) {
                        if (password == null)
                            throw new IOException("PEM is encrypted, but no password was specified");

                        decryptPEM(ps, password.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
                    }

                    return decoder.createKeyPair(ps, password);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    //LOGGER.log(Level.FINE, "Could not decode PEM Key using current decoder: " + decoder.getClass().getName(), ex);
                    // we couldn't decode the input, try another decoder
                }
            }
        }
        
        throw new IOException("PEM problem: it is of unknown type");
    }

}
```