# Android: Cipher with public key from php server

Tags: java, php, android, public-key-encryption

I am trying to encript a string in an Android app with a public key that I get from my php server.

php server code:

```
$res = openssl_pkey_new();
openssl_pkey_export($res, $privKey);

$pubKey = openssl_pkey_get_details($res);
$pubKey = $pubKey["key"];

echo $pubKey;
```

The server create correctly the key. In my app I store the public key in "response" variable. This var is like:
response = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----MIIB... etc ...wIDAQAB-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"

Android code:

```
String pass = "password";
String strEncryInfoData="";
try {
     KeyFactory keyFac = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
     KeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(Base64.decode(response.trim().getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT));
     Key publicKey = keyFac.generatePublic(keySpec);

     cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
     cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
     byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(pass.getBytes());
     strEncryInfoData = new String(Base64.encode(cipherText,Base64.DEFAULT));
} catch (Exception e){

}
```

When I run the application, appear this error:
java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.lang.RuntimeException: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag

I don't know why the code doesn't encript the password. Any idea? It is about the encode type?
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [InvalidKeySpecExeption when loadding the RSA private key from file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16233854/invalidkeyspecexeption-when-loadding-the-rsa-private-key-from-file)

Comment: Make sure key has no trailing or leading spaces.

Comment: No, that's not the problem. I checked.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the BEGIN header and END footer and all the newlines, then you get the Base64 encoded DER which you need to decode and pass to the `X509EncodedKeySpec` constructor. Here's some code:

```java
response = response.replaceAll("(-+BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-+\\r?\\n|-+END PUBLIC KEY-+\\r?\\n?)", "");
response = response.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "");
// Use Base64.NO_WRAP because: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32935783/java-different-results-when-decoding-base64-string-with-java-util-base64-vs-and/32935972
byte[] responseBytes = Base64.decode(response, Base64.NO_WRAP);
KeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(responseBytes);
```