# How to generate RSA Private key from *pem string in Java

Tags: java, rsa, private-key, pem, der

I want to generate the private key from a string(a `.pem` file) in Java.

```
private static final String test = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n" +
         "MIIEpAIBAAKCAQEAvcCH8WsT1xyrZqq684VPJzOF3hN5DNbowZ96Ie//PN0BtRW2\n" +
// and so on
         "-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";

try {
    String privKeyPEM = test.replace("-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n", "");
    privKeyPEM = privKeyPEM.replace("-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----", "");

    byte [] encoded = Base64.decode(privKeyPEM);

    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(encoded);
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    PrivateKey privKey = kf.generatePrivate(keySpec);
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The last line(generatePrivate function) is throwing this exception:

```
java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException : algid parse error, not a sequence
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePrivate(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePrivate(Unknown Source)
    at Test.main(Test.java:52)
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException : algid parse error, not a sequence
    at sun.security.pkcs.PKCS8Key.decode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.pkcs.PKCS8Key.decode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl.newKey(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.generatePrivate(Unknown Source)
    ... 3 more
```

If I change the private key to the value from a `.der` file it works properly, but I need to generate the private key file from a `.pem` file.

I attached a screenshot of the bytes printed as string(once hard-coded with \n and once hard-coded without \n) and once from the file.

[Bigger Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxhMP.png)

[image: Output]

The weird thing is that the output from the file is different to the output from the strings.

If I try to encode a `.der` file with Base64, the result is different than the string in the `.pem` file. Why is that so?

Comment: Did you find an answer at all ?

Comment: @SankarP nope not really.

Comment: okay. I have found the solution. Keys that begin with "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY" are pkcs1 encoded files. This pkcs1 encoding is not supported by Java unless you an external library like BouncyCastle. I ran into the same issue yesterday and after about 8 hours, found the solution. If you encode the private key with pkcs8 it will begin like "--- BEGIN PRIVATE KEY---" which will be handled by the stock java. HTH.

Comment: Dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243018/how-to-load-rsa-private-key-from-file

Answer (score 1):

You say that the last line is throwing exception, i.e.

`PrivateKey privKey = kf.generatePrivate(keySpec);`

Above line works on keyspecs being set correct, i.e.

`PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(encoded);`

So actual problem is with encoded bytes array. Have you done System.out after `byte [] encoded = Base64.decode(privKeyPEM);` and see what the output is.

I understand that if the message is in MIME format, then after certain characters it appends a combination of carriage return and newline so the strings are not too long for e-mail system or wherever you are using it.

The final String test has some '\n' in the original text which you use. You did get rid of other text in below line,

```
String privKeyPEM = test.replace("-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n", "");
    privKeyPEM = privKeyPEM.replace("-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----", "");
```

But, look at the string,

```
"MIIEpAIBAAKCAQEAvcCH8WsT1xyrZqq684VPJzOF3hN5DNbowZ96Ie//PN0BtRW2\n" +
// and so on
         "-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";
```

it may have some more '\n' left which may result in some unwanted characters when you generate keyspec. Try more System.out and see what the encoded byte array is like and also before that check String privKeyPEM and see if any extra character is not left in it.

Hope this hepls.

Comment: I uploaded the output of `encoded`. http://pastebin.com/YUsNdhgW. I also changed test to pure string without `\n` and it didn't work either.

Comment: I also uploaded a screenshot with the output as string.

Comment: Base64 decoding ignores linebreaks and usually all whitespace.