# PEM to PublicKey in Android

Tags: java, android, rsa, pem

I've seen a number of similar questions, but nothing has quite worked for me.  I am simply trying to convert an RSA public key that's in PEM format that I've retrieved from a server into a `PublicKey`in Android.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

EDIT: 
I've successfully used the following code to convert the PEM into a PublicKey, but upon encoding a message, I get unexpected output...

```
 public PublicKey getFromString(String keystr) throws Exception
    {
        // Remove the first and last lines

        String pubKeyPEM = keystr.replace("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n", "");
        pubKeyPEM = pubKeyPEM.replace("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----", "");

        // Base64 decode the data

        byte [] encoded = Base64.decode(pubKeyPEM);
        X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(encoded);
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PublicKey pubkey = kf.generatePublic(keySpec);

        return pubkey;
    }

    public String RSAEncrypt(final String plain) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException,
            InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, IOException {

        if (pubKey!=null) {
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);
            encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(plain.getBytes());
            Log.d("BYTES", new String(encryptedBytes));
            return Hex.encodeHexString(encryptedBytes);
        }
        else
            return null;
    }
```

The output looks like this:

```
b6813f8791d67c0fa82890d005c8ff554b57143b752b34784ad271ec01bfaa9a6a31e7ae08444baef1585a6f78f3f848eecb1706bf7b2868fccefc9d728c30480f3aabc9ac5c3a9b4b3c74c2f7d6f0da235234953ea24b644112e04a2ec619f6bf95306ef30563c4608ec4b53ed7c15736d5f79c7fa1e35f2444beb366ae4c71
```

when I expect something closer to:

```
JfoSJGo1qELUbpzH8d4QXtafup+J2F9wLxHCop00BQ4YS0cRdRCKDfHpFPZQYjNeyQj00HwHbz+vj8haTPbpdqT94AHAl+VZ+TPAiUw1U5EXLLyy4tzbmfVI7CwvMm26lwB4REzYUZdedha1caxMEfxQ5duB+x4ol9eRZM/savg=
```

Is there some formatting or file type that I'm missing?

Comment: Have you tried the approach in http://stackoverflow.com/q/3243018/ ?

Comment: I need to be able to do everything in-app...not using command line

Comment: if you need a base64 output, why did you decode your key to binary in line `byte [] encoded = Base64.decode(pubKeyPEM);`?

Comment: That's the expected input for a `X509EncodedKeySpec`

Comment: @cph2117 I am trying to use your code with my `.pem` file, however, my `.pem` file that contains the public key does not contain the strings `"-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n"` how should i proceed?

Comment: also, in your code, `Base64.decode` will give an error since it expects 2 input parameters, in your case you just input 1

Comment: @codeKiller It only takes one parameter per the docs (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Decoder.html). And as for the "Begin Public Key", you could just replace the first two lines with ```String pubKeyPEM = keystr```, but it sounds weird that a properly formed PEM wouldn't contain that line.

Comment: @cph2117 yes you are right, that is from Java utils, I am using Android and the docs indicates 2 params https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html since your post had the tag `Android` it made me confused, my mistake sorry. And yes, the .pem file I got is bit weird without any `Begin`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To answer my own question...The first output is in hex and the second output is in base 64.  Just change the return statement to             `return new String(Base64.encode(encryptedBytes));`
and you'll be good!

Comment: Please help me how to encrypt Public key which is in pem in Android. I couldn't find any solutions :-(

Comment: @Chandru - why would you want to encrypt a public key?

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't answer the question, but I find the content relevant. Posting as an answer because it doesn't fit as a comment.

### PEM vs DER

- PEM basically encapsulates a DER-encoded certificate or key.
- DER is binary, PEM is text; so PEM can easily be copy-pasted to an email, for example.
- What PEM does is:

  1. Encode the DER certificate or key using Base64, and
  2. Delimit the result with `-----BEGIN <something>-----` and `-----END <something>-----`.
- The key or certificate is the same, just represented in a different format.

Mostly paraphrasing from [ASN.1(wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One#Encodings).

### DER to Android/Java public key

> The following is an example of how to use a key factory in order to
>   instantiate a DSA public key from its encoding. Assume Alice has
>   received a digital signature from Bob. Bob also sent her his public
>   key (in encoded format) to verify his signature. Alice then performs
>   the following actions:
>
> ```
> X509EncodedKeySpec bobPubKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(bobEncodedPubKey);
> KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("DSA");
> PublicKey bobPubKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(bobPubKeySpec);
> ```
>
> ...

Note that `bobEncodedPubKey` is DER-encoded in this sample.

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/KeyFactory

### PEM to Android/Java public key

Similar to what is done for DER, but do the following beforehand:

1. Remove the `BEGIN`/`END` delimitation, and
2. Decode the content in Base64 to obtain the original DER.

(The question already shows code on how to do this.)