# How can I convert a string containing a public key in PEM `PKCS#1` format to a PublicKey object in Android app?

Tags: android, kotlin, cryptography, pkcs#1

How can I convert a string containing a public key in PEM `PKCS#1` format to a PublicKey object?

Currently, the code I have only successfully converts the string in `PKCS#8` format.

```
const val PKCS1PublicHeader = "-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----"
const val PKCS1PublicFooter = "-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----"
const val PKCS8PublicHeader = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----"
const val PKCS8PublicFooter = "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"
fun String.pemToPublicKey(algorithm: String): PublicKey? {
    return try {
        val isRSAPublicKey = this.contains(PKCS1PublicHeader)
        val cleanedKeyContent = this
            .replace("\\r\\n", "")
            .replace("\\n", "").let {
                if (isRSAPublicKey) {
                    it.replace(PKCS1PublicHeader, "").replace(PKCS1PublicFooter, "")
                } else {
                    it.replace(PKCS8PublicHeader, "").replace(PKCS8PublicFooter, "")
                }
            }

        val keyBytes = Base64.decode(cleanedKeyContent, Base64.NO_WRAP)

        println("Cleaned Key Content: $cleanedKeyContent")
        println("Is RSA Public Key: $isRSAPublicKey")

        val keySpec: KeySpec = if (isRSAPublicKey) {
            val modulus = BigInteger(1, keyBytes)
            val exponent = BigInteger.valueOf(65537)
            RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, exponent)
        } else {
            X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes)
        }

        val keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(algorithm)
        val publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec)
//            as RSAPublicKey

        println("Generated Public Key: $publicKey")

        publicKey

//        KeyFactory.getInstance(algorithm).generatePublic(keySpec)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Timber.e(e, "Invalid PEM key: $this")
        null
    }
}
```

Comment: You try to directly load RSA modulus and exponent from the binary data, but AFAIR all PKCS data should be ASN.1 encoded (you can decode the ASN.1 structure e.g. here https://lapo.it/asn1js/). The Java version to load PKCS#1 files is this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51706733/150978

Comment: Keys beginning with `"-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----"` are *not* PKCS8  and should not be labeled as such. Doing so will only confuse. The format is commonly referred to as SubjectPublicKeyInfo (or SPKI), and Java uses the unfortunately named class `X509EncodedKeySpec` to represent it. PKCS8 is a private key format.

Comment: @Robert: I suspect those answers are wrong. I think dave_thompson_085 has an answer showing how to do it, I'll try to find it.

Answer (score 1):

The PKCS#1 format is not directly supported. However, since the difference between PKCS#1 and X.509/SPKI is simply the leading `AlgorithmIdentifier`, this can be added to obtain the X.509/SPKI format which can be done conveniently with BouncyCastle.
The X.509/SPKI format generated this way can then be imported as usual via `X509EncodedKeySpec`:

```
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Sequence
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.DERNull
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.PKCSObjectIdentifiers
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.PrivateKeyInfo
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.AlgorithmIdentifier
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.SubjectPublicKeyInfo

...
val keySpec: KeySpec = if (isRSAPublicKey) {
     val algId = AlgorithmIdentifier(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.rsaEncryption, DERNull.INSTANCE)
     val publicKeyInfo = SubjectPublicKeyInfo(algId, ASN1Sequence.getInstance(keyBytes))
     X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKeyInfo.encoded)
} else {
...
```

which requires the corresponding dependency, e.g:

```
implementation 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk18on:1.77'
```

---

As just shown, BouncyCastle allows a convenient conversion of public RSA keys from PKCS#1 to X.509/SPKI.
In principle, however, this can also be implemented by yourself, but this is more complex. There are various SO posts which describe such an approach, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54246646/9014097) for Java.
For a Kotlin solution, this code can be converted to Kotlin, most easily with a converter tool (as e.g. included in Android Studio).

---

Note that BouncyCastle also allows the import of PEM keys, which would simplify your code significantly.
The following code can import PEM encoded public keys in *both* formats, namely in PKCS#1 format and in X.509/SPKI format:

```
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMParser
...
fun String.pemImport(algorithm: String): PublicKey? {
    val pemParser = PEMParser(StringReader(this))
    val subjectPublicKeyInfo = pemParser.readObject() as SubjectPublicKeyInfo
    val keySpec = X509EncodedKeySpec(subjectPublicKeyInfo.encoded)
    val keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(algorithm)
    val publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec)
    return publicKey
}
```

which, in addition to the above dependency, also requires the following dependency for the `PEMParser`:

```
implementation 'org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk18on:1.77'
```

---

Also consider the notes in the comments:

- After removing header, footer and line breaks and Base64 decoding, the result is the ASN.1/DER encoded key in public PKCS#1 or X.509/SPKI format and not the modulus, so the line `val modulus = BigInteger(1, keyBytes)` is wrong.
- What is referred to in the question as the PKCS#8 format is actually the X.509/SKPI format for public keys. PKCS#8 is a format for private keys.